# convert XMLdata to DOC and save it as TIFF

Tags: java, xml, tiff, doc

XML-DOC-TIFF

I am working on a POC where I need to convert XML data to a editable word document
and provide a button "save as tiff" on the word doc which saves as a TIFF image.
Can we achieve this using java ? I am running out of ideas.

-PD

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at XWPF and HWPF (http://poi.apache.org/hwpf/index.html), which provide Java APIs for reading and writing .docx files. Using this you should be able to map your XML data into a docx file.

Microsoft Word has a built in TIFF print capability. When you print, choose the Microsoft Office Document Image Writer printer, click on Properties->Advanced, then select TIFF.

Or were you trying to build a Java version of Microsoft Word?

Comment: well the issue is we have around 100 word templates in our database, we need to provide some way to select the word template and edit/enter some text fields and generate a tiff file out of it.